# How to clip raster image and convert to XML file?

Tags: raster, convert, clip, xml

I've tried to clip raster images with different software such as ENVI to keep metadata files and it was done successfully.

After this step, I want to convert the clipped image to XML file. in order to open this clipped image like the original one that I received from Satellite with XML file (once you click on the XML file it will open all bands with its own metadata).

I have tried (export to XML documentation) in ArcGIS and to XML online converters, But it didn't work.
Any guidance would be appreciated about converting clipped raster images to XML.

Comment: XML is usually no file format to safe raster images. The Metadata will often be provided in XML format, but the raster images should be .tif or another raster format (see https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/index.html).